# Quickly wiping multiple large 10tb+ drives

Tags: linux, files, partition, hard-disk, dd

I currently have multiple full 10, 12, and 14tb drives that I plan on selling. The problem I am facing is that I cant seem to find a decently fast method to to wipe to wipe them that doesn't say it will take 30+ weeks. In regards to the data I really don't care if its done securly or not because that data is literally completely random. I've looked at multiple sources online but haven't really been able to find a viable solution so if someone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does your drive support Secure Erase? https://superuser.com/questions/1336292/is-using-shred-to-wipe-linux-ssds-safe

Comment: 10TB is a **lot** of data, erasing a 10+TB HDD is going to take a significant amount of time, no matter what you do. The fastest SATA HDDs can do about 200MB/s sequential write, which is about 12GB/min or ~ 720GB/hour.  10TB divided by 720GB means that it will take almost 14 hours to completely write the drive once.  The average HDD is about half that speed, not much more than 100MB/s.  Also, the outer tracks on a drive are faster than the inner tracks so 200MB/s is the best-case.

Comment: Also note that most secure wipe programs will overwrite the drive multiple times with different bit patterns to ensure it's properly wiped.   Assuming, say, 7 wipe passes at slightly more than half a day per pass, that's roughly 4 days per drive.   If you can plug multiple drives in and wipe them simultaneously, you should be able to wipe several of them in less than a week, depending on how many spare sata ports or usb sata adaptors you have.

Comment: BTW, you will need good cooling on the drives while they're being wiped.  continuous writing for days at a time will generate a lot of heat.  If you don't have good drive cooling in the case, open the case and point a 240v mains-power standing fan at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is truly random, then what is on it means nothing, then who cares if anyone reads it.

Therefore, just do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd<whatever> bs=16KB count=1000`

That will just wipe the partition data and the first few sectors.

Comment: You'd rather want `bs=16KiB` or `bs=16K` or the standard `bs=16384`, not `bs=16KB` (let alone `bs=16KB,`) which is 16000 bytes. Note that 10+TB drives are more likely to have GPT partitioning with copies of the partition data at the start and end of the disk.

Comment: It really does not matter one little bit as long as either the MBR or GPT header is wiped. If they are gone, then an o/s would regard it as a blank disk. The data does not matter, nor any extended partitioning information. That 16KB came from a dart being thrown at a mythical chart.

Comment: Might as well do `head -c 16M /dev/zero > /dev/sd<whatever>` or `pv -Ss 16M < /dev/zero`... Not wiping the full disk means whoever buys the drive may start seeing warnings upon mkfs about a FS being there already for instance and could make them curious. Personally, I wouldn't sell a drive with my data on it.

Comment: Read the op's question, the data does not matter, it's random. And there will be no warnings, since the partition info has been wiped.

Comment: mkfs reports those warnings when it detects a FS signature at the start of the partition it is asked to format. So you'd get those warnings if the buyer creates a partition which starts on the same sector  as wherever there was a FS on the seller.

Comment: @Bib, if there's an intact backup GPT table, partitioning software may well use it if the one at the disk start is wiped. That's what the backup is for. So run something like `wipefs -a /dev/sdx` too. And I think Stéphane's point about bs=16KB is that forcing a 16000 byte block size may affect performance since the other relevant transmission block are likely to be powers of two in size. Also that comma at the end of the block size will give an error.

Comment: <shouting on>The op does not care... you are over analysing it, the data is random. That comma was a simple typing mistake.

Comment: @Bib, they care about the time it takes to wipe it. Also, if you insist on the assumption that they don't care, why do you even bother to wipe the beginning of the data? If they truly don't care about the data, then the partition table is of no consequence either and not wiping anything would be way faster than any alternative. On the other hand, if you decide to wipe the partition table, it would make sense to wipe the backup too, since it contains the same data...

Comment: There is no assumption on my part: From the op above...  In regards to the data I really don't care if its done securly or not because that data is literally completely random... please read what the op wrote.

Comment: @MrShouty If that's all the OP wants, then they can just use a partition editor like fdisk, gdisk, or parted to delete all the partitions.  That will, at least, do it correctly and delete them from any backup partition table(s) too, if any exist.   It won't prevent the partitions from being manually re-created, or prevent any data from being recovered (e.g. with tools like photorec or magicrescue).  To protect against that, the drives need to be wiped properly, which will be slow.   Personally, I'd physically destroy a drive rather than sell it, in case it had stuff I forgot about on it